# jQuery visibile list element only if current user is model user

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey i am trying to set a visibility of some part of list to be shown only if the currently log in user is the user from model. I try to do it by jquery. The code i have:

```
$(function() {
    $(('li.loggedelement').hide());
    if (@Model.openID !== @User.Identity.Name) {} else {
        $(('li.loggedelement').show());
    }
});
```

I want the function to determine at loading the view if the user is checking his own profile (so if @Model.openID == User.Identity.Name then its true) and then i want to show some extra options. Maybe i should give that class default visibility to hidden and then change it with a function.

EDIT
Thanks for help, im going to change the logic in Controller so that would be safer for users.

Comment: try `$('li.loggedelement').hide();` and `$('li.loggedelement').show();`

Comment: `$(('li.loggedelement').hide());` - I think there are too many brackets here. Try `$('li.loggedelement').hide();` instead. and the same for the show command.

Comment: well there is an error when i hit F12
" if (Model.openID !== User...) { " << Uncaught syntaxerror, unexpected identifier, so its like he dosnt expect me to start the bracket after if

Comment: Don't forget to close this question if  you do not need any further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a very bad option. If you want certain data only to be shown when a user is on his own profile, you should only render the html when that is the case.

You realize that any user that goes to any profile could just inspect  the page, and manually set the visibility so that he can see the data.

If you want the data not to be shown, use the server to not generate that specific part of the page rather than hiding it with client-side code. It's not safe.

Comment: ok thanks i'll better to this that way :) So i'm going strict to Controller and making there some logic

Comment: Exactly. You should *never* use javascript as your way of making something secure. A golden rule in development is that you need to assume the very worst in people, meaning that you need to assume that anyone is trying to exploit any security flaws that might exist in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
$(function() {
    if (@Model.openID != @User.Identity.Name) {
       $('li.loggedelement').hide();
     }
     else {
        $('li.loggedelement').show();
     }
});
```